# Upgrating from 1.7.2 to 1.8 [No menu for 1.8 yet]

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

Orchard v.1.7.2.0 Dashboard will only have menu 'Upgrade to 1.7' with these tabs inside:
Media (1.7), Taxonomies (1.7), Content Picker (1.7), Fields(1.5), Menu(1.5), Routes(1.4)

I install 1.7.2 with proof that 'Orchard 1.7.2' is showing at the right bottom of my dashboard.

How to find 'Upgrade to 1.8' menu then ? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Upgrade to 1.8' is a feature of Orchard 1.8, to migrate the contents created with previous versions.

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-1-8-Release-Notes